# How to export all installed versions of Java to a text file under Windows XP

Tags: java, command-line, windows-xp, batch-file

I'm looking to write a batch file I can deploy to 20-30 users that will export all of the enabled versions of Java out to a text file, which I can then pick up, and add to a troubleshooting effort we're working on.

I know that java -version will show the current version, but we're in an environment where we have multiple applications that use different versions.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your runtimes are all in the same folder,
You can grab the "JAVA_HOME" environment variable then just print a list of the folders in the parent directory of wherever it points.

However individual applications can bundle their own runtimes, which can be anywhere pretty much.

Since you reference -version though, I assume you are using it from the command line so pulling in JAVA_HOME and looking around there seems like a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Java Deployment Tookit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) with its method getJREs(). This returns an array of currently installed Java Runtime Environments.

Please be advised, that this a JavaScript and you probably won't be able to use it from command line.